# Code First Entity Framework disallows access to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to use code first to generate a database for an asp.net mvc application. the OrderItem class does get generated as OrderItems table in the database but I end up without having any access to it. what can I do to allow the following for example: `db.OrderItems.Find(id);`

the model is as follows:

```
namespace CustomerOrders.Models{

public class Customer
{

    public virtual int  CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Company { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmailCheck { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public virtual int OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual double OrderTotal { get; set; }
    public virtual double Tax { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public virtual int OrderItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual int OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual double PricePerItem { get; set; }
    public virtual double Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?  Is there data in the database?  Does db.OrderItems.Find(id); just throw an exception?

Comment: Maybe show the code how you create your dbcontext and the code how you try to use it?

Comment: The OrderItems table is inaccessible and it doesn't show up in the intellisense, all the other tables can be accessed as properties through code.

Comment: Have you added it correctly to the DbContext?

Comment: As I've already said, give us the actual code.. It's useless to guess the cause like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't got the declaration in your dbContext so Open up the dbContext and add  this: 
`public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }`

you should end up with this:

```
public class CustomerOrdersDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```